# What term sums up a situation where a person doesn't feel the need to weigh into an argument because the implications don't affect them?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What term sums up the situation in which a person does not feel they have to weigh into (or put much effort) into an argument because the implications will not affect them?

Thus, person X debates for the motion that group A are a worse bunch of people than group B. However, person X knows that the reality is that group A will be economically and strategically less better off than group B for a long time to come regardless of any debate. Therefore, in a formal debate, person X is not as motivated to persuade the debaters against the motion of the merits of his arguments because he knows that it will not affect reality.

Comment: .......politics

Comment: I'd say ambivalence.  You know, the "tug" we feel when on the one hand we want to do something, but on the other hand, we'd really rather not.  We have mixed emotions, in other words.

Comment: There is a point at which these kinds of questions are absurd. They sound more like a game rather than a legitimate question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [***indifferent***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/indifferent) :
>    1. Having no particular interest or concern; apathetic
>    2. Having no marked feeling for or against
>    3. Not mattering one way or the other

Person X is **indifferent** to the argument. or you might also say they are *disinterested*.

Answer (score 1):

[Pragmatism](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pragmatic) perhaps?

> Dealing with things sensibly and realistically in a way that is based
>   on practical rather than theoretical considerations

Comment: I suppose that covers it but I'm looking for something more specific to the situation described.